# Which is the best way to parsing RSS/Atom feeds with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I'm developing feed reader application in Rails. And i'm new to feed. I've a some questions.

1. Which is the best way to parsing thousand of RSS/Atom feeds with Rails or JavaScript /jQuery/ ?
2. Is there any way to get just feed title / not load whole feed / ?
3. Is there any way to get feed with limit ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can highly recommend feedzirra (it's a gem, really). I currently use FeedZirra in a production system that is continuously importing thousands of RSS and Atom feeds. It's very easy to use as well.

To your other points: no and no. A feed is a file on the web, which you need to download completely. You can however limit the number of articles you read or import into your database in your own code.

You need to parse the entire file, but it's possible to extract just the titles from each article.

Again, feedzirra makes this really easy for you to do.

http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing

Comment: That rails cast is very basic. See my comment on FeedZirra. It's fast and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do feed processing is to not do it and rely on a 3rd party Feed API. If you wan to do it yourself, you'll have to handle and maintain an offline process and/or queue system to fetch and parse the feed asynchronously. It's usually is a lot of work and adds little value to your project. You should use an API for this such as [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) or [Superfeedr's feed API](https://superfeedr.com/subscriber/).

We created a [Rails Engine to consume RSS](http://blog.superfeedr.com/consuming-rss-feeds-rails/) feed thru Superfeedr. It lets you subscribe, unsubscribe, retrieve past content from feeds and handles notifications of new content on your behalf.